# How to configure Spring Boot JPA for Cucumber Integration testing?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, cucumber

I have a Spring Boot project that is using PostgreSQL. I am using Spring Data and creating `CrudRepository`. This works fine for the application as I am able to use Auto Configuration and all the beans work. Now I am trying to write integration tests using Cucumber. For my tests, I want to use Spring JPA to connect to the embedded H2 database. I have created `DataSource` bean and also a repository interface that extends `CrudRepository`. When the tests boot up, it throws an exception along the lines of:

```
Specified class is an interface
```

I have even tried to do this manually by creating `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean` but, I am running into this exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'getEntityManagerFactory' defined in com.package.integration.repository.RepoConfig: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]
```

My `ConfigLoaderStepDefs`

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = [IntegrationTestConfig::class, JMeterRunner::class,
    RepoConfig::class])
class ConfigLoaderStepDefs : StepDefs
```

My `RepoConfig`

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories("<repo package>")
@EnableTransactionManagement
class RepoConfig {

    @Bean
    fun getEntityManagerFactory(): LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean {
        return LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean().also { factory ->
            factory.setPackagesToScan("<entities package>")
            factory.jpaVendorAdapter = HibernateJpaVendorAdapter()
        }
    }

    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "spring.datasource")
    @Bean
    @Primary
    fun getDataSource(): DataSource {

        val dataSourceBuilder = DataSourceBuilder.create()
        dataSourceBuilder.url("jdbc:h2:mem:memorydb")
                .username("sa")

        return dataSourceBuilder.build()
    }
}
```

My `CucumberIT`

```
@Tag("it")
@RunWith(Cucumber::class)
@CucumberOptions(
        plugin = ["html:build/reports/cucumber/cucumber-html-report",
            "json:build/reports/cucumber/cucumber-json-report.json"],
        features = ["classpath:features"],
        glue = ["com.package.integration"])
@SpringBootTest
class CucumberIT
```

Does anyone know who to configure JPA repository when working with cucumber?

Comment: I'm not sure if it works, but have you tried making all your classes open, as in: `open class` ?